# Select or_where in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to select record but when I use or_where don't follow what I need :

[image]

For the yellow line I don't need but it also appear. 
Let's see my code

```
$this->db->select('*')
                ->from('tblDiscountType')
                ->where('ShopLocationID', 4)
                ->or_where('ShopLocationID', NULL)
                ->where('DiscountApplicableId', 1)
                ->where('CountryID', 7)
                ->where('Current', -1);
        return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Please click Enter image description here to see the image

Comment: your question is unclear.. explain your question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `$this->db->last_query();` you can see the query generated.

Actually, it does something like

```
SELECT * FROM tblDiscountType 
    WHERE ShopLocationID = 4 OR ShopLocationID IS NULL 
    AND DiscountApplicableId = 1 AND ...
```

What you want is `WHERE (ShopLocationID = 4 OR ShopLocationID IS NULL) AND DiscountApplicableId = 1 AND ...`

Active Record is not that great for complex queries. So either write the query directly with `$this->db->query($your_query)` or trick active record like this :

```
$this->db->where("(ShopLocationID = 4 OR ShopLocationID IS NULL) AND DiscountApplicableId = 1 AND ...", NULL, FALSE);
```